# accessing webcam in web pages

Tags: html, camera, media, webcam

I am developing a web application.

In my guest registration page I need to **access web cam** for taking images of guests.

The image which I take could be able to stored in a specified location.

Which will be the best way to perform this.

Methods using java, JSP, html, java script or any other methods are welcomed.

Comment: Are the server and client the same machine?

Comment: Look into a signed java applet for this.  I did this for a topaz signature pad and it worked great, I was even able to get the signed applet to install the drivers for the signature pad so all they had to do was plug it in and visit the page with the applet.

Comment: The project will be hosted in a server so that it will be available in LAN of an office, So it will be different systems..

Comment: Then you will be wanting to access the webcam on the client, so the technologies on the server become irrelevant.

Comment: @Quentin, SO is it means it will not be possible to access client cam?

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny — No, it means that the fact you are using Java on the server is beside the point.

Comment: @Zoidberg, whether signed java applets will help me to find a solution?

Comment: @Quentin. In some sites, they are accessing our webcam for setting our profile pics. Actually that inspired me to do this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery Webcam Plugin does the hard work for you:

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Comment: If this works, I'd say this is the ideal solution with the least amount of work required, nicely done.

Comment: I don't have cam with me now(at office), after testing it with a cam only I could comment on it, Sorry.

Comment: I tested that page with a laptop. In first window it is showing the input from my camera, but after when I click take picture, it is not showing any actions.

Comment: When you click 'Take a picture instantly', it should display the picture taken in the box just below the camera view. Works here.

Answer (score 7):

Answering own question, as there is a better way using HTML5 is available.

**Option 1, Accessing default camera from the system**

**HTML**

```
Video Tag
<br/>
<div class="camera">
    <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
    <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button>
</div>
<br/>
Canvas
<br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**Script**

```
var width = 320;
var height = 0;
var streaming = false;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
        .then(function (stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("An error occured! " + err);
        });

video.addEventListener('canplay', function (ev) {
    if (!streaming) {
        height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);
        video.setAttribute('width', width);
        video.setAttribute('height', height);
        canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', height);

        streaming = true;
    }
}, false);

startbutton.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    takepicture();
    ev.preventDefault();
}, false);

clearphoto();

function clearphoto() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function takepicture() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (width && height) {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.95);
        if (dataURL && dataURL != "data:,") {
            var fileName = generateImageName();
            uploadimage(dataURL, fileName);
        } else {
            alert("Image not available");
        }
    } else {
        clearphoto();
    }
}

function generateImageName() {
    ... generate image name logic here ...
    return imageName;
}

function uploadimage(dataurl, filename) {
    ... upload logic here ...
}
```

**Screen shot**

[image: Screen shot]

**Option 2, Provide a list of available cameras in the system, and let user select the camera.**

**HTML**

```
<select id="videoSelect"></select>
    <button id="startCameraButton">Start Camera</button>
    <br/>
    Video Tag
    <br/>
    <div class="camera">
        <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
        <button id="takePictureButton">Take photo</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    Canvas
    <br/>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
```

**Script**

```
var width = 320;
var height = 0;
var streaming = false;
var localstream = null;

startCameraButton.onclick = start;
takePictureButton.onclick = takepicture;

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        .then(gotDevices)
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("An error occured while getting device list! " + err);
        });

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
    while (videoSelect.firstChild) {
        videoSelect.removeChild(videoSelect.firstChild);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
        if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
            option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
            videoSelect.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
}

function start() {
    stopVideo();
    clearphoto();
    var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
    var constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {deviceId: videoSource ? {exact: videoSource} : undefined}
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
            then(gotStream).then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
}



function gotStream(stream) {
    localstream = stream;
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
    // Refresh button list in case labels have become available
    return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
}

function handleError(error) {
    console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}

video.addEventListener('canplay', function (ev) {
    if (!streaming) {
        height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);
        video.setAttribute('width', width);
        video.setAttribute('height', height);
        canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', height);

        streaming = true;
    }
}, false);

clearphoto();

function clearphoto() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function takepicture() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (width && height) {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.95);
        if (dataURL && dataURL != "data:,") {
            var fileName = generateImageName();
            fileName = fileName + ".txt"
            uploadimage(dataURL, fileName);
        } else {
            console.log("Image not available");
        }
    } else {
        clearphoto();
    }
}

    function generateImageName() {
    ... generate image name logic here ...
    return imageName;
}

function uploadimage(dataurl, filename) {
    ... upload logic here ...
}

function stopVideo() {
    if (localstream) {
        localstream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
            track.stop();
            localstream = null;
        });
    }
}
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

**Option 3, let user select audio and video sources and audio output**

In option 2, user can select any particular camera. On top of that if user want to select audio source and audio output source also, modify the above code with below changes.

**HTML**

```
            audioInputSelect
            <br/>
            <select id="audioInputSelect"></select>
            <br/>
            audioOutputSelect
            <select id="audioOutputSelect"></select>
```

**Script**

```
function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
    while (videoSelect.firstChild) {
        videoSelect.removeChild(videoSelect.firstChild);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
        if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
            option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Microphone ' + (audioInputSelect.length + 1);
            audioInputSelect.appendChild(option);
        } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audiooutput') {
            option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Speaker ' + (audioOutputSelect.length + 1);
            audioOutputSelect.appendChild(option);
        } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
            option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
            videoSelect.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
}

function start() {
    stopVideo();
    clearphoto();
    var audioSource = audioInputSelect.value;
    var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
    var constraints = {
      audio: {deviceId: audioSource ? {exact: audioSource} : undefined},
        video: {deviceId: videoSource ? {exact: videoSource} : undefined}
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
            then(gotStream).then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
}
```