# Access webcam without Flash

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I want to create a video chat application using HTML 5 elements and JavaScript, and I don't want to use Flash to access the user's webcams.

How can I accomplish this using only HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: Untrue. Within certain constrains it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing webcam in web pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533773/accessing-webcam-in-web-pages)

Answer (score 18):

At the moment of writing this the best solution is WebRTC. It is [supported in Chrome, Mozilla and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc), but still unavaialble in Internet Explorer and Safari.

Minimalistic demo.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video></video>
    <script src="webcam.js"></script>
</body>
```

**webcam.js**

```
(function () {
    navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia);

    navigator.getMedia(
        // constraints
        {video:true, audio:false},

        // success callback
        function (mediaStream) {
            var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
            video.play();
        },   
        //handle error
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })   
})();
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/Taking_webcam_photos) or [there](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

Comment: This particular code won't work on Chrome until the user has clicked something within the DOM. I added a button that invokes the function above and everything works perfectly.

Comment: @taystack Do you have a fiddle or something ? I am curious on how.

Comment: @shifu https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#new-behaviors will tell you all the things.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact the provided example is great and inspired me, at the time of writing this answer, the [Navigator.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) function is obsolete. I've rewritten the provided example using the `video` tag's `srcObejct` and promise approach.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video-cam"></video>
    <script>
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
        .then(mediaStream => {
            const video = document.getElementById('video-cam');
            video.srcObject = mediaStream;
            video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => {
                video.play();
            };
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('You have to enable the mike and the camera');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Just an ordinary css styling 

#video-cam {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}