# JavaScript get WebCam resolution

Tags: javascript, webcam, resolution

Is it possible to get the Resolution of the WebCam though JavaScript? Has anyone done this before? If javaScript is not an option, what else we can go through?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out [Access webcam without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644612/controlling-webcam-via-html5/9646193#9646193)

You could build a flash webcam and pass the resolution to javascript.

I use http://www.scriptcam.com/ and last I remembered if you enable debug mode you can grab the resolution of the webcam from a javascript variable.

Comment: Thanks, ethree. I am actually using scriptcam for my web, too. Does this lib allowed to set different record resolution?

Comment: Check out Specifying a video capture size on the http://www.scriptcam.com/docs.cfm page. You can set any resolution you want and it will upscale etc to that resolution. I'm pretty sure no matter what resolution you set it to, your camera will always be running at the same resolution. It just scales it to fit to the height\width you select.

Comment: Yes, ethree. I saw this api for setting capture size, I tried 640*480, it works fine when the video is recording, but after recording, when I  start to playing the record video, the video picture will be paused there after 3 or 4 seconds, but the sound is still playing. I have forwarded this issue to their support, but they never give me an answer.

Comment: I've had nothing but trouble with scriptcam.... Maybe check out http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ ? I've been working with that for awhile too.. It has much better event handling. You'd have to do some hacking to get it to record video though.

Comment: Thanks, ethree. Never done with this before, no experience with Flash.