# Is it possible to detect webcam using jquery without using flash?

Tags: jquery, webcam

I am using a jquery plugin, which detects whether webcam present in your system or not.

But if any browser does not have flash, then first it says to download flash, but we dont need flash in our system.

Is there any jquery which detects webcam without using flash ??

Comment: See this anser [http://stackoverflow.com/q/9644612/4202224](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9644612/4202224)

Comment: No. This is not my solution. It is just showing how we can get stream. But before getting the stream, I just want to check whether system has webcam or not without using flash. If i use this solution then if system has browser, then it gives stream otherwise not. But i want to check webcam presence only.