# Take picture from webcam or mobile camera in web applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, camera

I'm developing a web application which browse and take pictures from local and also I want to capture images through the camera. Im using the following code and i can capture device camera.

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">
```

Now, I want to get the image and onchangeevent, convert to base64 and want to show in that page itself.

Kindly help me guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a mobile's camera from a web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581081/how-to-access-a-mobiles-camera-from-a-web-app)

Comment: Here is an interesting library that does that. [https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get base64 encoded data from html image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760764/how-to-get-base64-encoded-data-from-html-image)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as he wants to display the image on page, presumably without having to upload it first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing webcam in web pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533773/accessing-webcam-in-web-pages)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#cameraInput').on('change', function(e){
 $data = e.originalEvent.target.files[0];
  $reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(evt){
  $('#your_img_id').attr('src',evt.target.result);
  reader.readAsDataUrl($data);
}});
```

Comment: Any reason you're using the depreciated `bind` vs `on`?

Comment: Thanks! i was using this before now i'm using `on` instead of `bind`.

Comment: reader is $reader

Comment: You're right @Jay Dubal ! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Miles Erickson and Henock Bongi, you need to take reader.readAsDataUrl($data); out of the onload function in order that the onload fire.

If you don't want to use jQuery see below:

```js
function readFile(file) {                                                       
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = readSuccess;                                            
    function readSuccess(evt) {     
        document.getElementById("your_img_id").src = evt.target.result                   
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);                                              
} 

document.getElementById('cameraInput').onchange = function(e) {
    readFile(e.srcElement.files[0]);
};
```

Comment: Whats the point in answering a 2 years old post? either way it's better to use URL.createObjectURL instead of using the FileReader

Comment: The point is for reference for people like me who take 20 min figuring out why reader.onload is not firring :)

Comment: Yes you're right i forgot to take it out of onload function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function readFile(file) {                                                       
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = readSuccess;                                            
    function readSuccess(evt) {     
        document.getElementById("your_img_id").src = evt.target.result                   
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);                                              
} 

document.getElementById('cameraInput').onchange = function(e) {
    readFile(e.srcElement.files[0]);
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).