# Send Uri form image to server and save as image

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, url, uri

Here, I am able to get image uri's of the image captured through webcam but I don't know how to convert it to an image file and send to the node server.

URI length of around 4000+ and any helpful answer will be appreciated !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253777/take-picture-from-webcam-or-mobile-camera-in-web-applications

Comment: The "URI length of around 4000+" is called "data uri" of image. It contains all information of one image. You can make it as a file object and upload through form, or you can just post them as plain text and let server side program do the conversion job.